# Native C++ equivalent of ManualResetEvent from C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, events, synchronization

What's the equivalent methodology of `ManualResetEvent` in native C++.

Although the below page gives some APIs for C++, it seems to be valid for C++\CLI, and Windows Runtime scenarios only.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

My Operating System is Windows 8 (x64). IDE: Visual Studio 2012. I am working on a Windows application which has three layers: C#, C++\CLI, and C++ native. I required this feature in C++ native.

***Even though I currently need it only for Windows environment, it would be useful to know solution even for the Linux environment.***

Comment: C++ does not have such APIs. Even recent C++11 standard don't know about *events*. You should explain what operating system are you on. Did you consider using a cross-platform toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)?

Comment: My Operating System is Windows 8. IDE: Visual Studio 2012. I am working on a Windows application which has three layers: C#, C++\CLI, and C++ native. I required this feature in C++ native.

Comment: I will update the questoin to incorporate the above details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create an event object that you later signal with [SetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and reset with [ResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use a [wait function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait on an event object.

Comment: Note this is Windows only.

Comment: Yes, the question is for Windows.

Comment: Yes. This is for Windows, which suffices my current requirement. I would be grateful if someone can also guide me towards a Linux solution.